# How would I assert 'title' of page source in chrome. I have already asserted title in DOM

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I want to assert the 'title' in page source. When I right click on a page, I get two options. One is inspect element and the other is view page source. 
I would like to assert the 'title' in page source not the actual DOM.

I use Javascript, WebdriverIO

`get ogTitleValue() {
    return browser.element("//meta[@foo='og:title']");
  }`

I have tried this for DOM and it works. I want to assert title in page source

Comment: So you want to retrieve the original text value of the `<title>` element, before it is modified by other JS?

Comment: Yes. As soon as I lan on the page, I want to get the value of the title. Thank you